# docker push fails with unauthorized: authentication required , only for large images

Tags: docker

When I try to push docker images from my PC. I am getting "unauthorized: authentication required". This occurs only when I try to push docker image which are large in size(eg the ones that take 10 minutes to upload due to my slow internet ) . I am able to push docker images with the same command and image name from my PC when I use a smaller docker image. Is there some way to make docker push success for large docker images .

I am using docker for windows Docker version 19.03.5

Comment: Do you push to docker hub or to some private repository?

Comment: No I am pushing to docker hub public repository,